# How to solve this error after upgrade flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question regarding an error I am experiencing. After upgrading my flutter, I began encountering this error which did not occur prior to the upgrade. I have attempted to search for a solution through Google, however, I have not been successful in finding an answer. I am uncertain of how to proceed with resolving this error. If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions on how to solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Code:

```
 Uint8List? _toPngBytesForWeb() {
    if (isEmpty) return null;
    var pColor = img.getColor(penColor.red, penColor.green, penColor.blue); //The function 'getColor' isn't defined.
    
    Color backgroundColor = exportBackgroundColor ?? Colors.transparent;
    var bColor = img.getColor(backgroundColor.red, backgroundColor.green, backgroundColor.blue, backgroundColor.alpha.toInt());

    double minX = double.infinity;
    double maxX = 0;
    double minY = double.infinity;
    double maxY = 0;

    // point to create fixed size
    points.add(
        Point(Offset(0 + penStrokeWidth, 0 + penStrokeWidth), PointType.tap));
    points.add(
        Point(Offset(616 + penStrokeWidth, 0 + penStrokeWidth), PointType.tap));
    points.add(Point(
        Offset(616 + penStrokeWidth, 512 + penStrokeWidth), PointType.tap));
    points.add(
        Point(Offset(0 + penStrokeWidth, 512 + penStrokeWidth), PointType.tap));
    points.add(
        Point(Offset(616 + penStrokeWidth, 0 + penStrokeWidth), PointType.tap));

    points.forEach((point) {
      minX = min(point.offset.dx, minX);
      maxX = max(point.offset.dx, maxX);

      minY = min(point.offset.dy, minY);
      maxY = max(point.offset.dy, maxY);
    });

    //point translation
    //List<Point> translatedPoints = List();
    List<Point> translatedPoints = [];
    points.forEach((point) {
      translatedPoints.add(Point(
          Offset(point.offset.dx - minX + penStrokeWidth,
              point.offset.dy - minY + penStrokeWidth),
          point.type));
    });

    var width = (maxX - minX + penStrokeWidth * 2).toInt();
    var height = (maxY - minY + penStrokeWidth * 2).toInt();

    // create the image with the given size
    img.Image cheartDrawImage = img.Image(width, height);
    // set the image background color
    img.fill(cheartDrawImage, bColor);

    // read the drawing points list and draw the image
    // it uses the same logic as the CustomPainter Paint function
    for (int i = 0; i < translatedPoints.length - 1; i++) {
      if (translatedPoints[i + 1].type == PointType.move) {
        img.drawLine( //The named parameter 'x1' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
            cheartDrawImage,
            translatedPoints[i].offset.dx.toInt(),//Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 6 found.
            translatedPoints[i].offset.dy.toInt(),
            translatedPoints[i + 1].offset.dx.toInt(),
            translatedPoints[i + 1].offset.dy.toInt(),
            pColor,
            thickness: penStrokeWidth);
        
      } else {
        // draw the point to the image
        img.fillCircle(
            cheartDrawImage,
            translatedPoints[i].offset.dx.toInt(),
            translatedPoints[i].offset.dy.toInt(),
            penStrokeWidth.toInt(),
            img.getColor(255, 255, 255));
      }
    }
    // encode the image to PNG
    return Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(cheartDrawImage));
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fully reproducible example (missing imports here, I can't find img.fillCircle or isEmpty for instance), and the description of the error you get

Comment: +1 on the above comment and what is the "img" class that is cleary not set up properly but it is created in the code snippet provided

Comment: Error resolved. I resolved an error by adding the package image: 3.3.0, which I wasn't using before updating flutter.